# In trouble on github after local branch rename + push

Tags: git, push, rename

Had a local branch called GV, trying to use it to learn github.

```
git checkout GV
git remote add origin https://github.com/user627184/oscar.git
git push -u origin GV
git remote add oscar https://github.com/user627184/oscar.git
git branch -m master
git push oscar master
```

After all this, locally I have a branch called 'master', which is what I expected. But on github, now I have both master **and** GV, and it says that GV is the base for master. That doesn't seem right. Should I have done the rename and push differently? And now that I have this situation, how can I make my github repo look like my local repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming branches with `git branch -m` only affects branches in your local repository. If you want to "rename" a branch in a remote repo, you have to push a copy of the branch with the new name to the remote, then delete the old branch from the remote.

In your case, since you've already pushed `GV` as `master` up to your remote, all you have to do now is to delete `GV` from the remote (use one of the following, they both delete branches):

```
git push origin :GV
git push origin --delete GV
```

Note that, according to your description, it seems that `GV` might be the default branch in your remote repo, since you said that its the base branch for `master`. If that is the case, you won't be able to delete it from your remote until you've made some other branch the default, which you can do in the settings control panel for the remote repo on GitHub. If you need to pick a default branch, it's standard to use `master` as the default in the remote repo.

Comment: The first command you listed went ok, but the second one gave me an error: `unable to push to unqualified destination: GV`. Am I screwed now? ***Edit:*** Hmm, although the second command failed, github looks right. Could you help me understand what happened? ***Edit:*** d'oh! You said use ***one*** of those commands. Thanks much.